# Spin and Statistics: Feynman rules for any spin I - Weinberg 1964

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, lorentz-symmetry, spin-statistics

I am trying to understand the spin statistics theorem through the point of view of Weinberg's "The Quantum theory of Fields," (QToF) in which he cites a series of papers he published in 1964-1969 titled "Feynman rules for any spin I-III."

My main problem seems to be the "spin sum" $\pi(\textbf{p})$. In QToF pages 233-238 he puts forth a proof of the spin statistics theorem by constructing causal fields transforming according to the irreducible $(A,B)$ representations of the homogeneous Lorentz group. To the best of my understanding, he does this by using an earlier result (pages 195-198) that quantum fields be constructed in the following way:

A field $\psi_l(x)$ is built from components $\psi_l(x)^+$ and $\psi_l(x)^-$, which are Fourier transforms, in a linear combination:

$$
\psi_l(x)^+ = \sum_{\sigma, n}(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int{d^3p*u_l(\textbf{p},\sigma,n)*e^{ip*x}*a(\textbf{p},\sigma,n)}
$$

$$
\psi_l(x)^- = \sum_{\sigma, n}(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int{d^3p*v_l(\textbf{p},\sigma,n)*e^{-ip*x}*a^\dagger(\textbf{p},\sigma,n)}
$$

where $u_l(\textbf{p},\sigma,n)$ and $v_l(\textbf{p},\sigma,n)$ are coefficient functions, and

$$
\psi_l(x)\equiv \kappa_l\psi_l(x)^+ + \lambda_l\psi_l(x)^-
$$

He derives the coefficient functions as

$$
u_{ab}(\textbf{p},\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2p^0}}\sum_{a',b'}\left(e^{-\hat{\textbf{p}}*\textbf{J}^{(A)}\theta}\right)_{aa'}\left(e^{\hat{\textbf{p}}*\textbf{J}^{(B)}\theta}\right)_{bb'}\times C_{AB}(j\sigma;a'b')\tag{5.7.14}
$$

$$
 v_{ab}(\textbf{p},\sigma)=(-1)^{j+\sigma} u_{ab}(\textbf{p},-\sigma)\tag{5.7.15}
$$

Where $C_{AB}(j\sigma;a'b')$ are the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

The next step is to check the (anti)commutation relations, which are stated without derivation as: "We find

$$
\left[ \psi_{ab}(x),\tilde{\psi}^\dagger_{\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(x) \right]_{\mp}=(2\pi)^{-3}\int{d^3p(2p^0)^{-1}\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})\times\left[\kappa\tilde{\kappa}^*e^{ip*(x-y)}\mp \lambda\tilde{\lambda}^*e^{-ip*(x-y)} \right]}\tag{5.7.19}
$$

Here $\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}$ appears to be the "spin sum" defined by

$$
(2p^0)^{-1}\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p}) \equiv \sum_{\sigma}u_{ab}(\textbf{p},\sigma)\tilde{u}^*_{\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p},\sigma) =  \sum_{\sigma}v_{ab}(\textbf{p},\sigma)\tilde{v}^*_{\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p},\sigma)\tag{5.7.20}
$$

And

$$
\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})=\sum_{a'b'}\sum_{\tilde{a'}\tilde{b'}}\sum_{\sigma}C_{AB}(j\sigma;a'b')C_{\tilde{A'}\tilde{B'}}(j\sigma;\tilde{a}'\tilde{b}') \left(e^{-\hat{\textbf{p}}*\textbf{J}^{(A)}\theta} \right)_{aa'}\left(e^{\hat{\textbf{p}}*\textbf{J}^{(B)}\theta} \right)_{bb'}\left(e^{-\hat{\textbf{p}}*\textbf{J}^{(A)}\theta} \right)_{\tilde{a}\tilde{a'}}^*\left(e^{\hat{\textbf{p}}*\textbf{J}^{(B)}\theta} \right)_{\tilde{b}\tilde{b'}}^*\tag{5.7.21}
$$

And here is where I become confused. Weinberg places a citation to his 1969 paper indicating that this function $\pi(\textbf{p})$ was calculated explicitly there, and goes on to say that it turns out to be "the mass-shell value of a *polynomial* function P of $\textbf{p}$ and $p^0$:

$$
\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})=P_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p},\sqrt{\textbf{p}^2+m^2})\tag{5.7.22}
$$

and that P is even or odd according to whether $2A+2\tilde{B}$ is an even or odd integer

$$
P(-\textbf{p},-p^0)=(-)^{2A+2\tilde{B}}P(\textbf{p},p^0)\tag{5.7.23}
$$

The development of the problem then appears to lead to a vanishing condition on $(5.7.19)$, which assumes that $\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})$ is nonvanishing, and therefore it must be that the coefficients $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ satisfy these conditions.

We do this by indicating that a polynomial in $\textbf{p}$ and $\sqrt{\textbf{p}^2+m^2}$ can be written in a linear form by expressing even powers of $\sqrt{\textbf{p}^2+m^2}$ as terms in $\textbf{p}$. This leads Weinberg to state that $\pi(\textbf{p})$ can be written as:

$$
\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})=P_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})+2\sqrt{\textbf{p}^2+m^2}Q_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})
$$

Where

$$
P(-\textbf{p})=(-)^{2A+2\tilde{B}}P(\textbf{p})
$$

and

$$
Q(-\textbf{p})=-(-)^{2A+2\tilde{B}}Q(\textbf{p})\tag{5.7.26}
$$

This leads us to our conclusion via reframing $(5.7.19)$ as

$$
\left[ \psi_{ab}(x),\tilde{\psi}^\dagger_{\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(x) \right]_{\mp}=\left[\kappa\tilde{\kappa}^*\mp (-)^{2A+2\tilde{B}}\lambda\tilde{\lambda}^*\right]P_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(-i\nabla)\Delta_+(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y},0) +\left[\kappa\tilde{\kappa}^*\pm (-)^{2A+2\tilde{B}}\lambda\tilde{\lambda}^*\right]Q_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(-i\nabla)\delta^3(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y})
$$

Leading us to the condition that when $\textbf{x} \neq \textbf{y} $

$$
\kappa\tilde{\kappa}^*=\pm(-)^{2A+2\tilde{B}}\lambda\tilde{\lambda}^*
$$

And eventually the spin-statistics theorem through the case $A=\tilde{A}$ $B=\tilde{B}$ and the fact that $2A+2B$ differs from $2j$ by an *even* integer.

So I can understand his derivation if I understand why the spin sum takes this form (the form given by 5.7.23), why the $Q(-\textbf{p})$ polynomial picks up an extra $(-)$ sign in $(5.7.26)$, and how the term $\Delta_+(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y},0)$ appears in $(5.7.26)$. Does anyone understand these points? Because the manipulation of this $\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}(\textbf{p})$ term is the main sticking point for me here.

Furthermore, when applying the even or oddness of $\pi_{ab,\tilde{a}\tilde{b}}$ to $(5.7.19)$, there appears to be a failure of the associative property of multiplication where the $\kappa\tilde{\kappa}$ terms are not multiplied by $(-)^{2A+2B}$, while the $\lambda\tilde{\lambda}$ terms are. How does this occur?