# Weinberg Phys Rev 133, B1318 1964 - Spin Statistics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, spin-statistics

I have a question regarding Weinberg's derivation of the spin-statistics relation in the paper listed above (here at https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.133.B1318).

In this paper he investigates the commutator/anticommutator for fields built from representations of the homogeneous Lorentz group. Specifically, he builds the free field as:

$$
\phi_\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int\frac{d^3p}{\left[2\omega (\textbf{p})\right]^{1/2}}\sum_{\sigma'}\left[\xi D^{(j)}_{\sigma\sigma'}\left[L(\textbf{p})\right]a(\textbf{p},\sigma') e^{ipx}+\eta \{D^{(j)}\left[L(\textbf{p})\right]C^{-1}\}_{\sigma\sigma'}b^*(\textbf{p},\sigma')  e^{-ipx}\right]\tag{3.8}
$$

Where $D^{(j)}[\Lambda]$ are the $2j+1$ dimensional matrices represneting a finite Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$, with $D^{(j)}[\Lambda] \rightarrow(j,0)$ representation and $\bar{D}^{(j)}[\Lambda] \rightarrow(0,j)$ representation. We have

$$
D^{(j)}[\Lambda]=\bar{D}^{(j)}[\Lambda^{-1}]^\dagger
$$
and the boost $\Lambda=L(\textbf{p})$ is represented by

$$
D^{(j)}_{\sigma\sigma'}[L(\textbf{p})]=\{e^{-\hat{p}\cdot\textbf{J}^{(j)}\theta}\}_{\sigma\sigma'}
$$
With $sinh\theta\equiv \frac{\mid\textbf{p}\mid}{m}$.

Now we can make $[\phi_\sigma(x),\phi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(y)]_{\pm}$ in order to see how the two cases, fermion and boson, relate to the variables in this equation.

Explicitly, after accounting for the commutation relations between the creation and annihilation operators $a(\textbf{p},\sigma')$ and $b^*(\textbf{p},\sigma')$, we have

$$
\left[ \phi_{\sigma}(x),\phi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(y) \right]_{\pm}= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3m^{2j}}\int{\frac{d^3p}{2\omega(\textbf{p})}\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}^{(j)}(\textbf{p},\omega(\textbf{p}))\times}\{\mid\xi\mid^2 e^{ip(x-y)}\pm\mid\eta\mid^2 e^{-ip(x-y)}\}
$$

We are then told that the matrix $\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}^{(j)}(\textbf{p},\omega)$ is given by

$$
m^{-2j}\Pi(\textbf{p},\omega)=D^{(j)}[L(\textbf{p})]D^{(j)}[L(\textbf{p})]^\dagger=e^{-2\hat{p}\textbf{J}\theta}
$$

And

$$
\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}(\textbf{p})=(-)^{2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}p_{\mu_1}p_{\mu_2}...p_{\mu_{2j}}
$$

**Here** is where I get confused.

The commutator/anticommutator relations are then expanded using this definition of $\Pi$, as:

$$
\left[ \phi_{\sigma}(x),\phi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(y) \right]_{\pm}= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}(-im)^{-2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}...\partial_{\mu_{2j}}\int{\frac{d^3p}{2\omega(\textbf{p})}}\{\mid\xi\mid^2 e^{ip(x-y)}\pm(-)^{2j}\mid\eta\mid^2 e^{-ip(x-y)}\}
$$

How did this factor of $(-1)^{2j}$ materialize? At first glance, it seems to come from the form of $\Pi$, but let's take a closer look:

$$
p=-i\partial
$$
$$
\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}(\textbf{p})=(-)^{2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}p_{\mu_1}p_{\mu_2}...p_{\mu_{2j}}
$$

$$
\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}(\textbf{p})=(-)^{2j}(-i)^{2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}...\partial_{\mu_{2j}}
$$

$$
\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}(\textbf{p})=(+i)^{2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}...\partial_{\mu_{2j}}
$$

But $(i)^{-1}=-i$, such that

$$
\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}(\textbf{p})=(-i)^{-2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}...\partial_{\mu_{2j}}
$$

If you look back at the commutator/anticommutator, we see as coefficients to the integral:

$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}(-im)^{-2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}...\partial_{\mu_{2j}}
$$

But if we factor out $\Pi$ in the form we just saw...

$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}(m)^{-2j}(-i)^{-2j}t_{\sigma\sigma'}^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_{2j}}\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_2}...\partial_{\mu_{2j}}
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3(m)^{2j}}\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}(\textbf{p})
$$

And this is just what already existed in the integral before! So where on earth is this $(-)^{2j}$ term coming from? And why only on $\mid\eta\mid^2 e^{-ip(x-y)}$? Why does it not factor onto both terms $\mid\xi\mid^2 e^{ip(x-y)}\pm\mid\eta\mid^2 e^{-ip(x-y)}$ as 
$$
(-)^{2j}\mid\xi\mid^2 e^{ip(x-y)}\pm(-)^{2j}\mid\eta\mid^2 e^{-ip(x-y)} \equiv (-)^{2j}\left[\mid\xi\mid^2 e^{ip(x-y)}\pm\mid\eta\mid^2 e^{-ip(x-y)}\right]
$$

This factor should come from the math itself, as in either a result of the creation/annihilation operator actions, a result of the integration of $\Pi_{\sigma\sigma'}(\textbf{p})$, or something similar. But nowhere do I see this addressed.

In Weinberg's paper in 1964, he simply says "It follows from (4.2) that..." as explanation. In Novoshilov's reproduction of this proof (Particle physics textbook 1975 page 60-77 chapter 4), he states that he has used the fact that $D^J(-1)=(-1)^{2j}$, but the math

$$
\left[ \psi_{\sigma}(x),\psi^+_{\sigma'}(y) \right]_{\mp}= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int{\frac{d^3p}{2p_0}D^J_{\sigma\sigma'}}\left(\frac{p}{m}\right)\{e^{ip(x-y)}\pm\eta\eta^*e^{-ip(x-y}\}
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}D^J_{\sigma\sigma'}\left(\frac{-i\partial}{m}\right)\int\frac{d^3p}{2p_0}\{e^{ip(x-y)}\pm(-1)^{2j}\eta\eta^*e^{-ip(x-y}\}
$$

Does not reflect this. Instead it appears that he has just taken $D^J_{\sigma\sigma'}\left(\frac{p}{m}\right)\rightarrow D^J_{\sigma\sigma'}\left(\frac{-i\partial}{m}\right)$ via the trivial $\hat{p}\rightarrow -i\partial$.

Can anyone explain this? I have two other posts on the topic, but I realized that a finer phrasing of the issue that I am having may assist in clarity. For reference ([Spin and Statistics: Feynman rules for any spin I - Weinberg 1964](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/521188/) and [$(-1)^{2j}$ in the Spin-statistics theorem - Weinberg/Novozhilov/etc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522718/)).